# How to play a .h264 file in iOS (or) How to convert .h264 file in to .mp4 file programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, mp4

I have a .h264 file in my project bundle and i have to play it. I searched for long time and everybody suggested FFMPEG but there is no proper guidance. In another way at least suggest me how to convert this .h264 file in to .mp4 file programmatically by that way at least i can depend on MPMoviePlayer. Please suggest me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the native AVFoundation framework

https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/

> iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:
>   H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
>   H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
>   MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
>   Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in Audio Technologies